# Helios: Where are admin tools stated in the paper

Tags: voting

I read the Helios Paper [Helios: Web-based Open-Audit Voting](https://www.usenix.org/event/sec08/tech/full_papers/adida/adida.pdf).
In section 4.4 Anonymization they are saying that "once the voting period ends" the admin can "shuffle" (re-encrypt and permutate), "shuffle proof", "decrypt" and "decrypt proof" and then finally do the tally.

I tested an election and none of these tools were available except for the tallying part.

Did they change this?

Comment: Did you contact the authors or the coders where you downloaded? Note: Helios is used by  [IACR](https://www.iacr.org/elections/eVoting/finalReportHelios_2010-09-27.html)

Comment: No, I didn't try to contact them. I will give it a try. And yes, i know it is used by IACR. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the implementers automized the operation. Please, write your answer once you get the response/solution.